# Incorrect Index because of <option disabled> within a form select?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that handles a price change function on our website. There are only two prices that get passed to the server.  Here are my select options:

```
<select name="selector" id="amount" onchange="myFunction(this.selectedIndex);">
<option value="option1">option 1 - price 1</option>
<option value="option2">option 2 - price 1</option>
<option value="option2">option 3 - price 1</option>
<option value="option4">option 4 - price 1</option>
<option disabled>---------------------------------</option>
<option value="option5">option 5 - price 2</option>
<option value="option6">option 6 - price 2</option>
<option value="option7">option 7 - price 2</option>
<option value="option8">option 8 - price 2</option>
```

Here is the javascript that I have to handle the price change

```
function myFunction(input)
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
              document.getElementById("amount").value = price1;
          break;            
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
              document.getElementById("amount").value = price2;
          break;
    }
}
```

The issue that came up is that the price for option8 was not passed correctly and the user was charged price1 instead of price2. My thought is the disabled option is throwing off the index for the cases in my switch statement. Am I on the right track? Any input is welcome.

Comment: That is a likely cause. The easy solution is to use the value attr instead of index, but you really shouldn't manage pricing client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is precisely the problem. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6txrbuh/) to see how each option is indexed. An index of 4 corresponds to the disabled option; you need to eliminate `Case 4` and add `Case 8`.

What's happening is that the `switch` statement does nothing at all, because there is no case for index 8. So the `value` attribute stays at the same value it was at before you changed your selection. If the previous selection corresponded to price 1, that means it stays at price 1.

Comment: so if my second set of cases reads:

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
          document.getElementById("amount").value = price2;
          break;

that should solve the issue correct?

Comment: Yes. Cases 5 through 8 correspond to the options you have numbered 5 through 8, while case 4 corresponds to the disabled option.